# How to use data kept on GPU after model inference with tensorflow.js v3.13.0?

Tags: gpu, shader, webgl, tensorflow.js

I just got aware of a new feature in tfjs v3.13.0 (see https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/pull/5953). I am trying to use the new `dataToGPU()` method of Tensors to keep my model output on the GPU, since the `data()` method that sends the data back to the CPU takes too much time for my use case. But when I do call the new method and try to bind the `WebGLTexture` it creates to my `WebGLRenderingContext`, I get the following error.

```
WebGL: INVALID_OPERATION: bindTexture: object does not belong to this context
```

I'm guessing this is because the texture has been created on a context that is not the same as my canvas on which I want to bind the texture. So to fix that, there seems to be another feature for which it added the possibility of providing a `HTMLCanvasElement` or `OffscreenCanvas` to the declaration of the WebGL backend of tfjs (see https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/pull/5983). However, I am not declaring any backend in my code, so I'm not sure how I must use these features.

Could someone show me how the WebGL backend should be instantiated and used when running a model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an example how to register a custom `webgl` based backend, see the following on GitHub https://github.com/vladmandic/human/blob/main/src/tfjs/humangl.ts

A copy of this code is added here in case the above link ever fails:

```js
/** TFJS custom backend registration */

import type { Human } from '../human';
import { log } from '../util/util';
import * as tf from '../../dist/tfjs.esm.js';
import * as image from '../image/image';
import * as models from '../models';
import type { AnyCanvas } from '../exports';
// import { env } from '../env';

export const config = {
  name: 'humangl',
  priority: 999,
  canvas: <null | AnyCanvas>null,
  gl: <null | WebGL2RenderingContext>null,
  extensions: <string[]> [],
  webGLattr: { // https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/specs/latest/1.0/#5.2
    alpha: false,
    antialias: false,
    premultipliedAlpha: false,
    preserveDrawingBuffer: false,
    depth: false,
    stencil: false,
    failIfMajorPerformanceCaveat: false,
    desynchronized: true,
  },
};

function extensions(): void {
  /*
  https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/extensions/
  https://webglreport.com/?v=2
  */
  const gl = config.gl;
  if (!gl) return;
  config.extensions = gl.getSupportedExtensions() as string[];
  // gl.getExtension('KHR_parallel_shader_compile');
}

/**
 * Registers custom WebGL2 backend to be used by Human library
 *
 * @returns void
 */
export async function register(instance: Human): Promise<void> {
  // force backend reload if gl context is not valid
  if (instance.config.backend !== 'humangl') return;
  if ((config.name in tf.engine().registry) && (!config.gl || !config.gl.getParameter(config.gl.VERSION))) {
    log('error: humangl backend invalid context');
    models.reset(instance);
    /*
    log('resetting humangl backend');
    await tf.removeBackend(config.name);
    await register(instance); // re-register
    */
  }
  if (!tf.findBackend(config.name)) {
    try {
      config.canvas = await image.canvas(100, 100);
    } catch (err) {
      log('error: cannot create canvas:', err);
      return;
    }
    try {
      config.gl = config.canvas?.getContext('webgl2', config.webGLattr) as WebGL2RenderingContext;
      const glv2 = config.gl.getParameter(config.gl.VERSION).includes('2.0');
      if (!glv2) {
        log('override: using fallback webgl backend as webgl 2.0 is not detected');
        instance.config.backend = 'webgl';
        return;
      }
      if (config.canvas) {
        config.canvas.addEventListener('webglcontextlost', async (e) => {
          log('error: humangl:', e.type);
          log('possible browser memory leak using webgl or conflict with multiple backend registrations');
          instance.emit('error');
          throw new Error('backend error: webgl context lost');
          // log('resetting humangl backend');
          // env.initial = true;
          // models.reset(instance);
          // await tf.removeBackend(config.name);
          // await register(instance); // re-register
        });
        config.canvas.addEventListener('webglcontextrestored', (e) => {
          log('error: humangl context restored:', e);
        });
        config.canvas.addEventListener('webglcontextcreationerror', (e) => {
          log('error: humangl context create:', e);
        });
      }
    } catch (err) {
      log('error: cannot get WebGL context:', err);
      return;
    }
    try {
      tf.setWebGLContext(2, config.gl);
    } catch (err) {
      log('error: cannot set WebGL context:', err);
      return;
    }
    try {
      const ctx = new tf.GPGPUContext(config.gl);
      tf.registerBackend(config.name, () => new tf.MathBackendWebGL(ctx), config.priority);
    } catch (err) {
      log('error: cannot register WebGL backend:', err);
      return;
    }
    try {
      const kernels = tf.getKernelsForBackend('webgl');
      kernels.forEach((kernelConfig) => {
        const newKernelConfig = { ...kernelConfig, backendName: config.name };
        tf.registerKernel(newKernelConfig);
      });
    } catch (err) {
      log('error: cannot update WebGL backend registration:', err);
      return;
    }
    const current = tf.backend().getGPGPUContext ? tf.backend().getGPGPUContext().gl : null;
    if (current) {
      log(`humangl webgl version:${current.getParameter(current.VERSION)} renderer:${current.getParameter(current.RENDERER)}`);
    } else {
      log('error: no current gl context:', current, config.gl);
      return;
    }
    try {
      tf.ENV.set('WEBGL_VERSION', 2);
    } catch (err) {
      log('error: cannot set WebGL backend flags:', err);
      return;
    }
    extensions();
    log('backend registered:', config.name);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks you. I took a look at your code and realized that you are not using the new tfjs code to provide the instantiated MathBackendWebGL with a canvas directly, but you are instead getting the GPGPUContext of the canvas, which I assume is similar because the new tfjs code does that when we provide it a canvas. However, I still get the same WebGL error when trying to bind the texture created by tfjs to my WebGL context (the one from the same canvas).

Comment: Is there a place in your other files where you use the texture generated by tfjs?

Comment: I did try the same way you instantiated a new MathBackendWebGL object, but when I'm loading my model, I get 2 `[.WebGL-0x7fb0b16bc400]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glTexImage2D: invalid internalformat/format/type combination GL_LUMINANCE/GL_LUMINANCE/GL_FLOAT` and the output is not like I would expect it to be.

Comment: i'm using this in my app for a while now and it works without issues. yes, its using "old" method instead of providing canvas as constructor option, but "new" is same thing, just few lines shorter. btw, do make sure you set correct `webGLattrs` or canvas wont be usable.

Comment: I tried searching in your code and I can't find where you use the textures generated by your models inferences. I am trying to use the new `tensor.dataToGPU()` feature and it gives me the texture in a weird format and makes my entire browser laggy...

Comment: Ok, I discovered that the lag was caused by my GPU that stopped being detected, a reboot fixed it. And stacking 4 times my single channel output tensor allows me to get a texture that has the right shape. However, the texture is still not updating on the inferences after the first one.

Comment: you might need to dispose tensor and get a new one for each inference so `dataToGPU` method actually executes?

Comment: Yeah, that I already do.
`const gpuData = binarizedPrediction4.dataToGPU({ customTexShape: [modelHeight, modelWidth] });
const output = gpuData.texture;
gpuData.tensorRef.dispose();
binarizedPrediction4.dispose();`

Comment: if its not updating except the first time, maybe create an issue in tfjs repo....

Comment: Yeah, I have. The Google dev that worked on that feature does not answer very fast. She is supposed to finish writing documentation on how to use the feature by the end of this week, so hopefully I'll have some code to compare mine with today. Thanks for the help!

Comment: About my original question, the answer was to use webgl2 contexts because that's what tfjs expects. So if you edit your answer to mention it, I will flag your answer as accepted.

Comment: my example explicitly calls out `webgl2` in code and code comments - i dont bother with webgl1 at all, too many limitations nowadays